# Add an HTTP header more than once and send it separately using HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, cookies, .net-4.0

I need to send more than a `Set-Cookie` HTTP header using `HttpWebRequest` class.

Problem is first `request.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "[cookie string]")` adds the header as expected, but subsequent ones are concatenated in the first added header.

Default behavior complicates obtaning a set of cookies by the receiver of a given request, because isn't that easy split the header again in separate cookies' strings.

**Is there any way of adding *n* times some header?**

Perhaps some headers mustn't be repeated, but `Set-Cookie` is a valid use case, because receiver should read more than a cookie.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time looking for an out-of-the-box solution, I ended implementing an extension method to `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection`:

```
public static class WebHeaderCollectionExtensions
{
    public static ILookup<string, string> ToLookup(this WebHeaderCollection some)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        if (some.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] tempSplittedHeaders = null;

            foreach (string headerName in some)
            {
                if (some[headerName].Contains(";,"))
                {
                    tempSplittedHeaders = Regex.Split(some[headerName], ";,");

                    foreach (string splittedHeader in tempSplittedHeaders)
                    {
                        headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(headerName, splittedHeader));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(headerName, some[headerName]));
                }
            }
        }

        return headers.ToLookup(keySelector => keySelector.Key, elementSelector => elementSelector.Value);
    }
}
```

Thanks to this wonderful extension method, I'm able to convert headers' collection to a lookup, which allows duplicate keys, and at the end of the day, doing some processing, I get a list of all HTTP headers in separately:

```
string wholeCookie = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.ToLookup()["Set-Cookie"].Single(cookie => cookie.Contains("[Cookie name]"));
```

I hope sharing my solution will be a good contribution, as I guess others had or are having a similar case use!

Comment: If it comes to cookies, I believe that HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer property is what you were looking for, some more reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx